# Session Carrito y Login no se mantienen

Tags: php

Tengo una pagina con un login de usuario... este login mantiene una sesion con una variable que necesito a lo largo del proceso de la pagina.
En un punto hay un carrito que guarda la informacion en una sesion. Al querer iniciar esta sesion del carrito con la anterior sesion de login ya creada estas colicionan y no me permite crear otra sesion para el carrito.

En esta imagen se puede observar el inicio de la sesion del carrito

[image]

```
session_start();
class Cart {
    protected $cart_contents = array();
    
    public function __construct(){
        // Obtener el array del carrito de compras 
        $this->cart_contents = !empty($_SESSION['cart_contents'])?$_SESSION['cart_contents']:NULL;
        if ($this->cart_contents === NULL){
            // Establece el valor base de los items subidos.
            $this->cart_contents = array('total_items' => 0);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Devuelve la el contenido del array
     */
    public function contents(){
        // array_reverse reorganiza el array.
        $cart = array_reverse($this->cart_contents);

        
        unset($cart['total_items']);

        return $cart;
    }
    
    /**
     * Obtiene el insumo en especifico del array con su id

     */
    public function get_item($row_id){
        return (in_array($row_id, array('total_items'), TRUE) OR ! isset($this->cart_contents[$row_id]))
            ? FALSE
            : $this->cart_contents[$row_id];
    }
    
    /**
     * Total Items: Esta funcion nos devuelve la totalidad de items en el carrito (sesion)
     */
    public function total_items(){
        return $this->cart_contents['total_items'];
    }
    

    
    /**
     * Inserta los insumos al carrito y los guarda en la session
     */
    public function insert($item = array()){
        if(!is_array($item) OR count($item) === 0){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            if(!isset($item['idinventario'], $item['Nombreinsumo'], $item['Marca'], $item['qty'])){
                return FALSE;
            }else{
             
                // Cantidad
                $item['qty'] = (float) $item['qty'];
                if($item['qty'] == 0){
                    return FALSE;
                }
                // Marca
                $item['Marca'] =$item['Marca'];
                // Se crea el identificador del insumo en el carrito
                $rowid = md5($item['idinventario']);
                // Obetenemos la cantidad y si el producto ya se encuentra en el carrito este lo suma
                $old_qty = isset($this->cart_contents[$rowid]['qty']) ? (int) $this->cart_contents[$rowid]['qty'] : 0;
                // Re-actualizamos la informacion del producto con el identificador y la cantidad le sumamos.
                $item['rowid'] = $rowid;
                $item['qty'] += $old_qty;
                $this->cart_contents[$rowid] = $item;
                
                // Guardamos los cambios en el carrito
                if($this->save_cart()){
                    return isset($rowid) ? $rowid : TRUE;
                }else{
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Actualizacion del carrito
     */
    public function update($item = array()){
        if (!is_array($item) OR count($item) === 0){
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            if (!isset($item['rowid'], $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']])){
                return FALSE;
            }else{
                // Cantidad
                if(isset($item['qty'])){
                    $item['qty'] = (float) $item['qty'];

                    // Borrar producto del carrito cuando la cantidad es 0
                    if ($item['qty'] == 0){
                        unset($this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']]);
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                }
                
                //Array_intersect retorna los valores del array1 en todos los indices y mantiene sus claves
                $keys = array_intersect(array_keys($this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']]), array_keys($item));
                
                
                // Diferenciamos todas las id y nombres de los insumos como unicos.
                foreach(array_diff($keys, array('idinventario', 'Nombreinsumo')) as $key){
                    $this->cart_contents[$item['rowid']][$key] = $item[$key];
                }
                // Guardado en el carrito
                $this->save_cart();
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Guardar Carrito en la sesion
     * @return  bool
     */
    protected function save_cart(){
    $this->cart_contents['total_items']; 
        foreach ($this->cart_contents as $key => $val){
            // Aseguramos que el array contenga los indeces
            if(!is_array($val) OR !isset($val['qty'])){
                continue;
            }
     
            $this->cart_contents['total_items'] += $val['qty'];
        }
        
        // Si el carrito se encuentra vacio se elimina la session del mismo
        if(count($this->cart_contents) <= 1){
            unset($_SESSION['cart_contents']);
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            $_SESSION['cart_contents'] = $this->cart_contents;
            return TRUE;
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Remove Item: Funcion que nos permite eliminar el producto del carrito

     */
     public function remove($row_id){
        // Eliminamos el insumo del carrito a traves de su identificador unico y guardamos el carrito.
        unset($this->cart_contents[$row_id]);
        $this->save_cart();
        return TRUE;
     }
     
    /**
     * Funcion que permite eliminar la sesion cuando esta no tenga ningun insumo
     */
    public function destroy(){
        $this->cart_contents = array('total_items' => 0);
        unset($_SESSION['cart_contents']);
    }

}

?>
```

La sesion que tengo en el login es "rut" y el archivo donde esta el carrito contiene tambien consultas a la base de datos que ocupo en otras vistas.

La imagen muestra que yo al logear y estar en la vista HOME.php y incluir el archivo ../Modelos/ValidarConsultas.php interfiere la sesion creada con anterioridad y la sesion del carrito.

[image]

Este codigo pertenece a la vista de home.

```
session_start();

$sesion=$_SESSION["rut"];
include("../Modelos/ValidarConsultas.php");
$idpersona=idpersona($sesion);



if($sesion==null || $sesion=""){
    header("location:../index.php");
    die();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CONTRUNITY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.php">
        <img src="../img/LogoContrunity.png" alt="CONTRUNITY" style="width:80px;" class="rounded-pill"> 
        </a>
    </div>
  <div class="nav justify-content-end">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Opciones
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista insumos</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista empleados</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../Controladores/CerrarSesion.php">Cerrar sesion</a>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron ">
      <h1 class="display-4" style="font-family: 'Archivo Black';"> BIENVENIDO</h1>
      <hr class="my-4">
      
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="ListaInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Buscar Insumo</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/520925/search-sort.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
        <a href="ListaEmpleados.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Buscar Empleado</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/520925/search-sort.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="RegistroInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Registro Insumo</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/509701/add-to-cart.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
        <a href="RegistroPersonas.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Registro Empleado</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/510317/user-plus.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="SolicitudInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Solicitar Insumos</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/6094/insert-file.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
        <a href="ListaSolicitudes.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
          <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
            <h5>Lista Solicitudes</h5>
            <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/522164/list.svg" style="width:60px;">
          </div>         
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora cuando entro a la vista del carrito y agrego productos al carrito este agrega productos, pero elimina la sesion creada del rut.

En esta imagen se ve los productos del carrito agregados y arriba las id de los productos.
[image]

Y en este pequeño estracto de codigo se observa que la sesion que pido en la vista del carrito es la de rut y la escribo en pantalla a traves de "echo"... pero me salen las id de los productos no el rut del usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo claro que las sesiones son nombradas de manera diferente y que en ningun momento nombre las sesiones igual... aqui adjunto las diferentes funciones del carrito a traves de metodos "get"

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
include("../Modelos/ValidarConsultas.php");
$cart = new Cart;
include("../Controladores/conexion.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action'])){
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'addToCart' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $idinventario = $_REQUEST['id'];
        
        $query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM inventarios WHERE idinventario = ".$idinventario);
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $itemData = array(
            'idinventario' => $row['idinventario'],
            'Nombreinsumo' => $row['Nombreinsumo'],
            'Marca' => $row['Marca'],
            'qty' => 1
        );
        
        $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData);
        $redirectLoc = $insertItem?'../Vistas/SolicitudInsumos.php':'../Vistas/PedirInsumo.php';
        header("Location: ".$redirectLoc);
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'updateCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $itemData = array(
            'rowid' => $_REQUEST['id'],
            'qty' => $_REQUEST['qty']
        );
        $updateItem = $cart->update($itemData);
        echo $updateItem? 'ok':'err';die;
       
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'removeCartItem' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $deleteItem = $cart->remove($_REQUEST['id']);
        header("Location: ../Vistas/PedirInsumo.php");
    }elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'Solicitud' && $cart->total_items() > 0 && !empty($_SESSION['sessCustomerID'])){
        // insert de productos.
        $insertOrder = $db->query("INSERT INTO orden (customer_id, total_price, created, modified) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['sessCustomerID']."', '".$cart->total()."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
        
        if($insertOrder){
            $orderID = $db->insert_id;
            $sql = '';
            // Obtener insumos del carrito
            $cartItems = $cart->contents();
            foreach($cartItems as $item){
                $sql .= "INSERT INTO orden_articulos (order_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES ('".$orderID."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['qty']."');";
            }
            // INSERSION DE ORDEN EN BD
            $insertOrderItems = $db->multi_query($sql);
            
            if($insertOrderItems){
                $cart->destroy();
                header("Location: OrdenExito.php?id=$orderID");
            }else{
                header("Location: Pagos.php");
            }
        }else{
            header("Location: Pagos.php");
        }
    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

La seesCustomerID es la id del usuario que la obtengo a traves del dato de la sesion rut por eso es tan importante mantener ambas sesiones tanto login como carrito ya que necesito saber que usuario hizo esa solicitud.
Mi pregunta es si existe alguna manera de ocupar estas sesiones de manera simultanea o si existe alguna otra manera logica y plantear el problema.